# How to extract first element of each array into array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Sometimes when you are performing db queries, you might need only the first element of the arrays whereas PHP result array will give you an array of arrays containing one element each. What is the best way to extract each element into an array e.g.

Say you have `array(array('silas'), array('douglas'))`

but you need `array('silas', 'douglas');`

Comment: `array_column` if it's php 5.5+, `foreach` loop if not

Comment: There is a [userland implementation](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column) of array_column() that will work with versions of PHP prior to 5.5

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_map('array_shift', $your_array);`

Comment: Note that `array_map` is slower than `foreach($your_array as $elem) { $new_array[] = array_shift($elem); }`

Comment: array_column() is significantly faster than either, if it's available to use

Comment: Yeah, I've learnt that too now, but PHP 5.5+ is a bit futuristic.

Comment: Timings on an array with 256k elements: array_column time = 0.021726 s;
   array_map time = 0.241532 s;
     foreach time = 0.174203 s